# Sorting a list by conditional criteria

Tags: python, list, sorting

I know how to simply sort a list in Python using the `sort()` method and an appropriate lambda rule. However I don't know how to deal with the following situation :

> I have a list of strings, that either contain only letters or contain a specific keyword and a number. I want to sort the list first so as to put the elements with the keyword at the end, then sort those by the number they contain.

e.g. my list could be: `mylist = ['abc','xyz','keyword 2','def','keyword 1']` and I want it sorted to `['abc','def','xyz','keyword 1','keyword 2']`.

I already have something like

```
mylist.sort(key=lambda x: x.split("keyword")[0],reverse=True)
```

which produces only

```
['xyz', 'def', 'abc', 'keyword 2', 'keyword 1']
```

Comment: What do you mean here by 'specific' keyword ? Will it always be word: 'keyword' or it could be anything but space separated with number?

Comment: @Suparshva Anything but space separated with number.

Comment: @Suparshva and the keyword is unique in that only strings with it have a number afterwards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**One liner solution:**

```
mylist.sort(key=lambda x: (len(x.split())>1, x if len(x.split())==1 else int(x.split()[-1]) ) )
```

**Explanation:**
First condition `len(x.split())>1` makes sure that multi word strings go behind single word strings as they will probably have numbers. So now ties will be there only between single word strings with single word strings or multi word strings with multi word strings due to first condition. Note there won't be any ties with multi word and single word strings. So if multi word string I return an integer else return string itself.

**Example:**

> ['xyz', 'keyword 1000', 'def', 'abc', 'keyword 2', 'keyword 1']

**Results :**

```
>>> mylist=['xyz', 'keyword 1000', 'def', 'abc', 'keyword 2', 'keyword 1']
>>> mylist.sort(key=lambda x: (len(x.split())>1, x if len(x.split())==1 else int(x.split()[-1]) ) )
>>> mylist
['abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'keyword 1', 'keyword 2', 'keyword 1000']
```

Comment: len(x.split())>1 will always return False given len(x.split())==1, so can you just write False, or 0 instead?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "last" element that doesn't contain your keyword as a barrier to sort first the words without the keyword and then the words with the keyword:

```
barrier = max(filter(lambda x: 'keyword' not in x, mylist))
# 'xyz'    

mylist_barriered = [barrier + x if 'keyword' in x else x for x in mylist]
# ['abc', 'xyz', 'xyzkeyword 2', 'def', 'xyzkeyword 1']

res = sorted(mylist_barriered)
# ['abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'xyzkeyword 1', 'xyzkeyword 2']

# Be sure not to replace the barrier itself, `x != barrier`
res = [x.replace(barrier, '') if barrier in x and x != barrier else x for x in res]
```

`res` is now:

```
['abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'keyword 1', 'keyword 2']
```

The benefit of this non-hard-coded approach (outside out `'keyword'`, obviously), is that your keyword can occur anywhere in the string and the method will still work. Try the above code with `['abc', 'def', '1 keyword 2', 'xyz', '1 keyword 4']` to see what I mean.

Another easy way to do this, with a divide-and-conquer approach:

```
precedes = [x for x in mylist if 'keyword' not in x]

sort_precedes = sorted(precedes)

follows = [x for x in mylist if 'keyword' in x]

sort_follows = sorted(follows)

together = sort_precedes + sort_follows

together
['abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'keyword 1', 'keyword 2']
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort with a tuple by first checking if the item starts with the keyword. If it is, set the first item in the tuple to 1 and then set the other item to the number following the keyword. For non-keyword items, set the first tuple item to 0 (so they always come before keywords) and then the other tuple item can be used for a lexicographical sort:

```
def func(x):
   if x.startswith('keyword'):
       return 1, int(x.split()[-1])
   return 0, x

mylist.sort(key=func)
print(mylist)
# ['abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'keyword 1', 'keyword 2']
```

Answer (score 0):

I am prefixing the strings containing "keyword" with the highest value in the ascii table so they go at the end when evaluated by the built-in sort function. https://repl.it/H66r/1

`mylist.sort(key=lambda x: x if (x.find("keyword", 0) != -1) else '\127' +  x)`

EDIT: 
This wasn't sorting the keywords strings according to their numbers. 
Using the tuple solution we can come up with this : https://repl.it/H66r/8
The first value of the tuple index is very low if not containing "keyword" and its actual value otherwise. Letting the system sort all the keys with similar values.

`mylist.sort(key=lambda x: (- sys.maxsize, x) if (x.find("keyword", 0) == -1) else (int(x.split(" ")[1]), x) )`

Comment: Is there a simple way of sorting the numbers as numbers and not strings? i.e. with your solution `keyword 1000` comes between `keyword 1` and `keyword 2`

Comment: This does a lexicographical sort on the numbers instead of a numerical sort, so 1000 will come before 2

Comment: @MosesKoledoye yeah, I get that, which is why I'm asking if there's a simple way of throwing a numerical sort on top of it.

Comment: @Demosthene Well, I addressed that in my answer by converting to `int`